# No install alongside windows option

Tags: system-installation

I downloaded Ubuntu and put it onto a DVD and i assume it works fine because the disk is working. I looked around at the options and noticed that I could install alongside windows, but I chose to just try it. Now I've decided to install it alongside windows(vista) but now the option is no longer there. Any ideas..?

Comment: More details on your windows install and current hard drive partition setup is necessary.  This is with 12.10 (latest)? Thanks!

Comment: Current windows is VistaOS and the current partitions are 6.84 free and the rest VistaOS....

Comment: Do I need to create free space by shrinking the windows part?

Comment: That would typically be good (as you're not getting prompted for the option).  Back up your Windows data if you haven't. You can resize in either Windows or Ubuntu/Linux.  Just a sanity check -- you have done poweroff and reboot since the last OS load?

Comment: What do you mean? I have powered off several times when there has been no option for alongside installation( to try again, cause I feel like sometimes a reboot fixes things)

Comment: OK, that's what I meant by sanity check.  I had assumed you had done that, but just wanted to make sure.  So, yes, I would recommend manually partitioning.

Comment: Any luck with this?

Answer (score 0):

As you suggest, creating free space by shrinking the partition would be a good way to get past this.  (Obligatory warning : Back up your Windows data if you haven't.)

You can partition/resize in either Windows or Ubuntu/Linux.

In one case, I had to use a utility in Windows to actually create an ext3 partition in the free space that Ubuntu would see.  After that, I was able to boot the Ubuntu DVD, and was finally able to select the ext3 partition and format it to ext4 for Ubuntu without harming the existing Windows installation.